# Usage of 'Both'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-case, sentence-meaning, complex-sentences

" Innocence is courage and clarity both."

I heard this sentence. Is it correct?

Comment: You often see *"both*" at the end of sentences, especially after pronouns (e.g. I like singing and dancing - I like them both). After nouns, this isn't incorrect, but an informal and perhaps dialect variant.

Comment: @Justin it could be poetic too

Comment: @marcellothearcane - Yes, you're right. It could be poetic too. Though it also depends on the context in which the OP wishes to use "*both*" in.